# why is a crystal needed to program microcontrollers

Tags: microcontroller, spi

I'm making a programmer for the AT89s52 in parallel mode so that I can program other micros as well. I had bad luck using the spi interface with my computer.

I am able to flawlessly program an at89c4051 with the pc parallel port without adding a crystal.

I've seen numerous of circuits that the at89s52 and even at89c51 show a crystal attached for prograamming.

Why does the at89x5x series of chips need a crystal for programming when parallel mode (not spi) is used?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the programming hardware the designers built into the chip.

Usually they want to be to program it (in some mode) without external components so they can be supplied pre-programmed.

Beyond that, if it increases the cost of the chip and does not benefit high-volume customers it won't necessarily get implemented. Those particular parts are really old chips, and transistors cost significantly more in the days of old.

Comment: "...so they can be supplied pre-programmed." ... I don't think the AT89Cx051 series come pre-programmed? and I don't need a crystal to program it.

Comment: Microchip will supply eg. AT89C51RC2 pre-programmed. "for as low as $0.23"